# Yahoo finance no longer work?

Tags: yahoo-finance

I used to get exhange rate from yahoo finance api by javascript with following url:
http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/jpy=x,eur=x/quote?format=json

but now it no longer work! I have search on the net but no luck.
Any help would be great, Thank!

**Update: it is working if open with chrome mobile**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it seems like Yahoo! has discontinued the (private, mostly-undocumented) Yahoo Finance API that many have been using for their currency data. All responses seem to be returning `"Not a valid parameter"`. I suppose there's a chance they may switch it back on, but they don't officially support that API anywhere as far as I can tell.

I created [Open Exchange Rates](https://openexchangerates.org) about five years ago, and our exchange rate API now supports a community of tens of thousands of developers - and their tens of millions of users - with accurate, up-to-date information.

Please feel welcome to check out our Forever Free service at https://openexchangerates.org.

Our API is in a simple, original JSON format, which has actually caught on as a standard method for displaying rates because it's so simple to work with (unlike the Yahoo API, which required you to parse the obscure nested objects to pull out the basic info you needed...)

If you need assistance porting from the deprecated Yahoo! API, we'll be happy to assist via email.

(I am the founder of Open Exchange Rates.)

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, I will try in the weekend.

Comment: Easy setup and get all what I wanted. 1000 request limited is more than enough for my app.thank you! but Yesterday, open exchange was slow--the site and API,  but today is good --what happen? one more question why the rate is lower than google finance?

Comment: Now we just need "Open Stock Quotes" and that would be perfect ;-)

Answer (score 2):

indrakula is right, and their response helped me, but...

I also needed to retrieve exchange rate tickers (i.e. USDGBP=X). This was not trivial, and I had to do some searching. The URL format in this case is http://www.google.com/finance/info?q=CURRENCY%3aUSDGBP. This URL returns a JSON body and not something else as the alternative URLs mentioned in one of the comments for that reply. Also note the link with the parameter descriptions seems to be out-of-date, but I found most of them are self-explanatory. So don't rely on that link.

Note: I wanted to post this as a comment to indrakula's answer, but one needs 50 reputation to comment! I'm new! I tried to submit this as an edit to their answer but it was (rightly) refused.

Comment: Thank @giro83 this is great. I prefered google rate. is there any way to get multiple rate compare to usd?

Answer (score 0):

use google  http://www.google.com/finance/info?q=GOOGL

paramater description here http://www.networkerror.org/component/content/44.html?task=view

Comment: how can i get currency rate? this gives only stock.

Comment: I'm able to get currency rate but the response is web-doc not json! [google converter](https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=USD&to=JPY) AND [google getprices](https://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=USDJPY&x=CURRENCY)